# undefined local variable or method `key' for Google::Auth::DefaultCredentials:Class

Tags: google-api-ruby-client

When I do:

```
scopes =  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly']
contacts = Google::Apis::MirrorV1::MirrorService.new
something = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
```

I get in the 3rd line:

> Unable to read the credential file specified by
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: undefined local variable or method
>   `key' for Google::Auth::DefaultCredentials:Class

I'm downloading the json file from developers console, which has the following structure:

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "...",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_email": "",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "",
    "client_secret": "...",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost:3000/...",
      "http://localhost:3000/..."
    ],
    "javascript_origins": [
      "http://localhost:3000"
    ]
  }
}
```

And set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable pointing to the .json file.

I'm not sure why I get the error.

Thanks in advanced